# value in ng-options is stored in ng-model as object instead of string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have a "format" object which contains a list of "datamapping" objects. My datamapping object contains these fields (but we're only concerned with `concatenation`):

```js
dataMapping.column = null;
dataMapping.datatype = null;
dataMapping.dataMapping = null;
dataMapping.mappingName = "Mapping " + (format.datamappings.length+1);
dataMapping.hasConcatenation = true;
dataMapping.concatenation = ["", ""];
```

```html
<div style="margin: 1px 0px" ng-repeat="mapping in format.datamappings track by $index"> <!-- using a class for css is not working (even if it has !important), dont know why-->
    <hr width="50" align="left">
    {{mapping.mappingName}}
    <div style="margin-left: 13px"> <!-- using a class for css is not working (even if it has !important), dont know why-->
     Column
     <input class="form-control inline width-small" ng-class="{'unfilled': mapping.column == '' || mapping.column == null}" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || event.charCode == 8)" type="text" ng-model="mapping.column"/>
     Datatype
     <select class="form-control inline width-medium1" ng-class="{'unfilled': mapping.datatype == '' || mapping.datatype == null}" ng-model="mapping.datatype">
      <option value="text">text</option>
      <option value="number">number</option>
      <option value="decimal">decimal</option>
     </select>
     Data mapping
     <select class="form-control inline width-medium1" ng-class="{'unfilled': mapping.dataMapping == '' || mapping.dataMapping == null}" ng-model="mapping.dataMapping">
      <option value="manuf">Manufacturer</option>
      <option value="product_name">Product Name</option>
      <option value="unit">Unit / Quantity</option>
      <option value="price">Price</option>
     </select>
     <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteMapping(format, $index)">Delete mapping</button>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mapping.hasConcatenation" ng-click="includeConcatenation(mapping)"> Has Concatenation</label>
                    

                                        <!-- LOOK HERE -->
     <div ng-if="mapping.hasConcatenation">
      Concatenation
      <select ng-repeat="concat in mapping.concatenation track by $index" class="form-control inline width-medium1" ng-options="x.mappingName for x in format.datamappings" ng-model="mapping.concatenation[$index]"></select>
                          </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Let's say we have 2 mappings in the dropdown list: "Mapping 1" and "Mapping 2". When I select a value from the dropdown, instead of a string being stored in the `concatenation` array (`mapping.concatenation[$index]`), it stores an object instead as shown in the image below. And if you expand the object you will see that it apparently references itself infinitely.

[image: Console]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try once with below code, because you are displaying mappingName and selecting entire object , if you want to select only name try as below

`ng-options="x.mappingName as x.mappingName for x in format.datamappings"`

Reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

> Using select as will bind the result of the select expression to the
>   model, but the value of the  and  html elements will
>   be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for
>   object data sources) of the value within the collection. If a track by
>   expression is used, the result of that expression will be set as the
>   value of the option and select elements.

Comment: You saved my another extra 1 hour on searching this :)